# Laravel - Add additional where constraints from Eloquent Model belongsToMany relationship

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am new to Laravel (using v7) so I apologise if I am doing this incorrectly.
I have a custom subscription setup for my users.

I have my users table

| id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe |
| 2 | Jane | Doe |

I have my subscriptions table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Basic |
| 2 | Bronze |
| 3 | Silver |
| 4 ​ | Gold |
| 5 ​ | Platinum |

And a subscription_user  pivot table

| id | user_id | subscription_id | created_at | expired_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2021-02-01 23:22:12 | 2021-03-21 08:22:12 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 2021-03-21 08:22:12 | 2021-04-04 09:03:21 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 2021-04-04 09:03:21 |  |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2021-01-01 01:00:00 | 2021-01-05 05:30:00 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-05 05:30:00 | 2021-01-06 08:34:10 |

So as per the above entries, `John Doe` subscribed on the Basic subscription, then upgraded to the Platinum and then finally downgrading to the Silver. Which is his current subscription.

I have the following methods (within User.php) for first getting a list of the users subscriptions

```
public function subscriptions()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subscription')
    ->orderby('pivot_created_at', 'desc')
    ->withPivot('created_at', 'expired_at')
    ->withTimestamps();
}
```

And then to get the current subscription

```
public function subscription()
{
  return $this->subscriptions->first();
}
```

However there could be instances where by a user has all subscriptions expired, therefore they have no current subscription in place. i.e in the above records `Jane Doe` who subscribed to 2 plans but both have expired.

If i call `$user->subscription()` on Jane Doe it still returns the latest expired entry.
I have tried added `where()` clauses into my `subscription` method but it has no effect:

```
public function subscription()
{
  return $this->subscriptions->where('expired_at', NULL)->first();
}
```

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to achieve? I need a method to fetch all the users subscriptions, whether they are active or expired. (which I have - is this the best way?)

But then also fetch the current subscription which should always not have an `expired_at`.
It seems I cannot add any further conditions within mt `subscription` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the query builder for the subscription method using `subscriptions()` instead of the collection `subscriptions`

```php
public function subscription()
{
  return $this->subscriptions()->whereNull('expired_at')->first();
}
```

calling `$this->subscriptions` is equivalent to `$this->subscriptions = $this->subscriptions()->get()`. where `$this->subscriptions` returns a collection.

`$this->subscriptions()`, using the method, return a query builder.

PS: it did not trigger an error calling `first()` because a Collection has a method called `first()` too.